# When press ⌘ + d debug menu wont appear

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen

In my react native project when I press

> `⌘ + d debug menu won't show up`
>   The problem is the splashScreen won't hide is there any way to debug?

Comment: You may have run the app in release mode. Use debugging mode. Then debugging menu will appear.
run react-native run-ios on terminal for debug mode.
run react-native run-ios --variant=release for release mode

Comment: @Paras Watts nice one 
You would have helped me on issue but u corrected the spelling hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens because of your App is in release mode.

Try below steps.

**Make sure for debugging application your build is in release mode not in debug mode  and  for the release time you can set release al well**

> Path to change release to debug mode: Product(Menu) > Scheme > Edit
>   Scheme > Build Configuration

and reset (Menu > Hardware > Erase all content and settigs) your simulator then try run again and press `⌘ + d` it will work.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: How do I make my app to release mode ? I have already tried restarting simulator, deleting and recreating ios/build file but none of them worked .

Comment: @PratikKhadka Please check my updated ans. or go to... Path to change release to debug mode: Product(Menu) > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Build Configuration

Comment: Which version of Xcode is it ? M inside ios/project.xcworkspace!!

Comment: I couldnot find the path you mentioned above I guess you were referring too  Project.xcworkspace > Info > Use Release for command line build (Pick Release from drop down ) and yes it was actually in release.

Comment: @PratikKhadka No Man! You are going wrong...

This is in the Xcode help. You could easily look it up:


 **1** Choose "Edit Scheme" from the "Product" menu.
 **2** Click on the “Edit Schemes…" button
 **3** Select the Tun options from left menu.
 **4** Build configuration dropdown are there.

Comment: Try in command line this: 
react-native run-ios --configuration Debug 
OR IF YOU ARE IN ANDROID:
react-native run-android --configuration Debug

Answer (score -1):

Just restart your Simulator from xcode.

Comment: Woooww So unusual answer never thought of that ..haha
Jokes apart I have done it several time already

Comment: i was facing this issue every time when I open a popup and then hot reload even my keypad wont work inside emulator